# How to disabled(Not show) 'OK' button when field is empty in ionic(1) popup

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am new to ionic. I have created two check boxes inside the popup. OK button should hide when both of the check boxes are not checked.[I had attached my ionic popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ4hF.jpg)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Hope this helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XubtJ.jpg)

Comment: I have rendered popup from script side. Common class only generated for both cancel and Ok button. So how can apply this.

Comment: yes, that's exactly right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I fixed this.** 
I get input fields value using ng-change in angular. I have applied CSS Opacity 0.4 to the OK button while changing the input value. Using **res.preventDefault();** this function to prevent the OK button's action when input fields are empty.